# Channel swap when reading created image with Gdal

Tags: python, gdal, digital-image-processing

I use a function on python (3.5) to create GTIFF with GDAL:

```
def array2raster2(fname,   matriz, geot, proj):
    drv = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    dst_ds = drv.Create(fname, matriz.shape[1], matriz.shape[0], 3,  gdal.GDT_UInt16)
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(geot)
    dst_ds.SetProjection(proj)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(matriz[:, :, 0])  # write r-band to the    raster
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(matriz[:, :, 1])  # write g-band to the raster
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(matriz[:, :, 2])# write g-band to the raster
    dst_ds.FlushCache()
    dst_ds=None
```

and works fine, but when I open again the image with `gdal.Open()` and `gdal.ReadAsArray()` and check the shape, instead of i.e. (100, 101, 3), it shows (3, 100, 101), can anyone tell me why?

Also when I open the GTIFF on ENVI the orders of band is BGR, when I am saving the image on RGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set colour interpretation of your bands:

```
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_RedBand)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_GreenBand)
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(3).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_BlueBand)
```

Also you can try to reverse the order of channels while filling pixels values.

```
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(matriz[:, :, 0])  # write r-band to the    raster
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(matriz[:, :, 1])  # write g-band to the raster
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(matriz[:, :, 2])# write g-band to the raster
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first option was the one I needed, problem solved

Comment: actually there has been another issue, when add a 4th band, NIR in this case, when opening on ENVI again the 4th band is show as RED, how can I fix that?