# Again Band swap when reading created image with Gdal

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, envi

As previously seen [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261118/channel-swap-when-reading-created-image-with-gdal/261195#261195) I created a function to save a raster with `gdal`on python:

```
def array2raster2(fname,  rasterOrigin, pixelWidth, pixelHeight,array,  proj, shape):

    originX = rasterOrigin[0]
    originY = rasterOrigin[1]
    drv = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    dst_ds = drv.Create(fname, shape[1], shape[0], 4)#, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
    dst_ds.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    dst_ds.SetProjection(proj)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(array[:, :, 0])  # write r-band to the    raster
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(array[:, :, 1])  # write g-band to the raster
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(array[:, :, 2])
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(4).WriteArray(array[:, :, 3])

    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_RedBand)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(2).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_GreenBand)
    dst_ds.GetRasterBand(3).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_BlueBand)

    dst_ds.FlushCache()
    dst_ds=None
```

And added the last 3 lines for `SetRasterColorInterpretation()`and worked great when using 3 channels.

But now I am using now 4 channels, 4Th channel for NIR band, as on SPOT satelite images or Pleiades, but when opening again on ENVI or QGIS the 4th band is shown as the first, what do I need to do to fix that? I checked on `gdal.GCI_`values and only shows for 3 bands, I understood that `gdal.GCI_AlphaBand`is for transparency band so I don't need that...yet.

And second issue, I have the borders of the image as 0, how can I set that value to Nodata so I don't have borders visualized on ENVI or any other GIS?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `ALPHA=NO` creation option to avoid the 4th band (NIR) being interpreted as alpha channel and finally set NIR band color interpretation as undefined:

```
co = ["ALPHA=NO"] # creation options
dst_ds = drv.Create(fname, shape[1], shape[0], 4, gdal.GDT_UInt16, options = co)

# your code here

dst_ds.GetRasterBand(4).SetRasterColorInterpretation(gdal.GCI_Undefined)
```